# CSS Background syntax issue

Tags: html, css, background

```
background: url('../city-lights.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center / cover  transparent;
```

How does that code work?
I get that no-repeat stops the bg image from repeating, fixed means it's fixed to it's position, center center means it's centered along the x and y axes, cover means it'll cover the whole screen even if it has to stretch or shrink for it, and transparent renders it transparent.

What does the '/' do? Why's it there?
In case anyone thinks, this is a perfectly legit code that works, but not written by me.
Also, in case someone wonders, I did not know what to google, I tried something, it didn't give back helpful results.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: @MarcB So '/' is a part of the 'bg-size' in the 'background' short syntax. Thanks! You should add that as an answer. With added details if you could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [W3 CSS Shorthand Reference](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference#Enhancements_in_CSS3):

> ...if you want to include the background-size value in the shorthand
>   syntax, you need to:
>
> - Explicitly include background-position values even if these are the same as the defaults (see above).
> - Write background-position values before background-size values.
> - **Put a slash in between these two pairs of values**.

Comment: That helped. Would have been better if they would develop it such that the shorthand syntax is shorter. That is, we can ignore the defaults from writing again.